# Quote about the history of particle physics

Tags: physics, quote, particle-physics

I have a (very) vague remembrance of a quote about the history of particle physics, particularly (I think?) the development of the standard model. As I recall, it was about how it was a very exciting time, and the continual discoveries were like "strange wonders carried back from the edge of understanding" or something to that effect. I know this is very vague, but I would appreciate any help sourcing this quote. I may have seen it in a seminar talk or conference, but my own googling has turned up nothing.

Comment: Sounds like a Sidney Coleman quote, or a S Weinberg rendition of one. Have you looked at the 2005 Fest?

Comment: Right! It is indeed Coleman. From Aspects of Symmetry: "These lectures span fourteen years, from 1966 to 1979. This was a great time to be a high-energy theorist, the period of the famous triumph of quantum field theory.  And what a triumph it was, in the old sense of the word: a glorious victory parade, full of wonderful things brought back from far places to make the spectator gasp with awe and laugh with joy." Thanks so much!

Comment: Ah, I knew about this imagery, but your exact quote is a joining of two famous halves in science fiction, of which SC was a fan, and I gathered it may have appeared elsewhere in exact form. It is still ringing a bell...

Comment: @EvanRule you can submit and answer to your own question.